# Is it possible to to automatically add your Nop Quick Tabs in Nopercommerce 4.60.3

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0, nopcommerce-4.1, nopcommerce-4.2

Good day ya'll, is there a way to add Nop Quick Tabs automatically to my Website after upgrade, Im using No Source Code version 4.60.3.

Eveytime I do an upgrade I have to add the Tabs(Datasheets) manually to the Tab section.

After upgrade the Tab just dissapear.

The Nop Quick Tabs exist, but is there any chance to add them automatically without having to do it manually. Like with some code you know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using SevenSpike's Nop Quick Tab plugin?

Comment: Im using Seven Spikes, im using Nopcommerce 4.60.3. no source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SevenSpike's Quick Tab plugin then then update plugins.json file with plugin's system name in installed list under Presentation > App_Data folder

This will resolve your issue on upgradation of nopCommerce.

Comment: Hey Raju im abit confused, all the code is there, please see below code


`{
      "SystemName": "SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.NopQuickTabs",
      "Version": "4.6"
    },`